# During the importing of tensorflow this error came up everytime.I did tried to uninstall and then install it again .It still gives the same error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

this is the error after import tensorflow as tf code on jupyter notebook

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dll file, you'll have to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable and to make sure the DLL is installed in the system32 folder according to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512)

I hope this helps resolve this issue!

Comment: How can you tell?

Comment: Please see the link I've provided along with my answer, the issue is the same as what you're facing now, tensorflow requires some library dependencies when installed in windows

Answer (score -1):

on "ANACONDA.NAVIGATOR"  MAIN PAGE CHANGE THE "APPLICATION ON TENSORFLOW OR TF"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQu2x.png)

Comment: From Review: Please take some time to improve the quality of your answer. I could barely understand what you wrote in this answer. Also, please do not post your answer completely written in uppercase letters. Please read the S.O. rules: [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

**INSTALA E IMPORTA TODO ESTO!**

```
    ! Pip install pandas
    ! Pip install keras
    ! Pip install tensorflow
    import pandas as pd
    import keras
    import tensorflow
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As this is an English-only site, please avoid writing answers in other languages.